# Rails: ActiveRecord preload alludes me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am not able to grasp how the ActiveRecord `preload` method is of use.

When I do, for example, `User.preload(:posts)`, it does runs two queries but what is returned is just the same as `User.all`. The second query does not seem to affect the result.

```
User Load (3.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
Post Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Can someone explain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output is the same, but when you'll call `user.posts`, Rails will not load your posts from the database next time:

```
users = User.preload(:posts).limit(5) # users collection, 2 queries to the database
# User Load ...
# Post Load ...
users.flat_map(&:posts) # users posts array, no loads
users.flat_map(&:posts) # users posts array, no loads
```

You can do it as mutch times as you want, Rails just 'remember' your posts in RAM. The idea is that you go to the database only once.